# the type attribute is not working for form_widget

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

All the attributes work perfectly fine except the "type" attribute

I want to set the type of input(form_widget) to 'password' but it's not working! (the password shows up, it's not covered )

here is the code of my twig page :

```
username : {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': 
{
    'class': 'input100',
    'placeholder': 'Username',
    'name':'_username', 
    'type': 'text'} 

 }) }}

password : {{ form_widget(form.password, {'attr':
 {
    'class': 'input100', 
    'placeholder': 'password', 
    'name':'_password', 
    'type': 'password'}  
    })}}
```

Comment: Do you need to define the form widget type in your Twig template? Do you have a FormType?

Comment: is it throwing an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set up the type from the Form Class you can found it in thr folder

src/Form/

```
->add('username', TextType::class)
```

and import the class like this

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
```